# Authenticate user for Sharepoint Online using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, authentication, sharepoint

I am totally new to linking Sharepoint Online with vb.net program, any advise would certainly help.

I have added reference for the 2 *.dll* file, *Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client* and *Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime*. They are downloaded from the link [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)
.

Below will be my code,

```
 Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
 Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
 Imports Microsoft
 Imports System.Net
 Imports System.Security

Public Class FilesRetrievalFromSharePoint
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Using ClientContext As New ClientContext("https://sample.sharepoint.com/Home.aspx")

        Dim password As New System.Security.SecureString()

        For Each c As Char In "pw@12345".ToCharArray()
            password.AppendChar(c)
        Next


        ClientContext.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("user1@sample.com", password)
        Dim web As Web = ClientContext.Web

        ClientContext.Load(web)
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    End Using
End Sub
```

And the few other classes below *End Sub*

```
Private Class SharePointOnlineCredentials
    Implements ICredentials

    Private password As SecureString
    Private v As String

    Public Sub New(v As String, password As SecureString)
        Me.v = v
        Me.password = password
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCredential(uri As Uri, authType As String) As NetworkCredential Implements ICredentials.GetCredential
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

The error which I will hit at `ExecuteQuery()` is

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I understand it is due to authentication issue, and the *Sharepoint* url is meant for authorized users in the corporate. Assuming the credentials in the code, belongs to an authorized user.

Is it due to wrong coding or it could be due to the corporate IT security policy?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line
Using ClientContext As New ClientContext("https://sample.sharepoint.com/Home.aspx")

to
Using ClientContext As New ClientContext("https://sample.sharepoint.com")
If you are planning to use a different site
use
Using ClientContext As New ClientContext("https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite")

Do not use the page to connect to the site.

Comment: hi @Guruparan, thank you for your reply. and nope, it still gives me the 403 error.

Comment: @TanStanley are you replacing the site url properly?
https://sample.sharepoint.com

Comment: for testing purposes i have used  Using ClientContext As New ClientContext("https://sample.sharepoint.com"). However the error occurs before i can get a response from the web application.

Comment: Did you try it with a different site url in your tenant ?
something like ClientContext As New ClientContext("{DifferentSiteURL}").

Comment: hi @Guruparan, i managed to get it working by referencing the ClaimsAuth.dll. I found the dll file from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c

Comment: great Happy to hear :)